# How to download a software by clicking on a link in MVC 4

Tags: razor, model-view-controller

I have created a link using `@Html.ActionLink("Click Here to download ", "download", "home")` and by clicking on it need to install a setup if it is not already installed. Please any one help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the controller's action return the file that you would like to execute.  The browser will then prompt the user to either save or open the file.